# download raw texture data to get around cors?

Tags: javascript, browser, webgl

WebGL texImage2D is strict in terms of disallowing "tainted" images to be used as a source.

In some cases this can be solved by adding a `crossOrigin` property to the image element before loading. However, this still requires cooperation from the server to send the appropriate headers.

Is it possible to, instead, download the raw data and then convert it to an in-memory image for then sending onto WebGL? Or will this be considered "tainted" as well?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to download the raw data would be to use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` which are subject to the same cross-origin limitations and would also need the appropriate headers sent with the server's cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

As @Quentin says, there is no direct workaround.

The indirect workaround is use a cors proxy. Your webpage asks the proxy for the asset and that proxy asks the real server for the asset and then forwards it to you adding on the cors headers. Of course that would be expensive since the proxy has to pay for a server running and for bandwidth of every asset. If you search for "cors proxy" though you can find lots of examples and/or services.